# Possible complications for not closing database cursors?

Tags: oracle, database-cursor

What are the possible complications and repercussions if you do not close cursors for your Oracle database?

Comment: You will hit the `ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded ` error eventually

Comment: The reason I'm asking this is that for the company I work for, our product is getting the `ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded` error, probably because one of the teams refuse to close their cursors saying that it takes too long. I need some solid evidence that this error is the result of their practices.

Comment: Takes too long to code, or too long in the procedure to close the cursor? If the first one, get a nerf gun and say "Dance, dance dance!.. now go and fix my procedure!" Maybe show a sample that expresses this scenario, so you can get further advice.

Comment: They say it's a performance hit to close and open cursors all the time.

Comment: Can't you use a cursor pool? Open them once, use them, return them to the pool.

Comment: The ORA-01000 can also appear on an infinite loop. If pertinent, perhaps you should check your PL/SQL procedure loops.

Comment: Your **product** is getting `ORA-01000`. If you're trying to sell something that's breaking because of this then you have to start testing ways to try to fix it. Because of the error closing cursors seems like a good place to start... I suspect those that refuse will have to start

Answer (score 4):

Since your developers are complaining about the performance hit of repeatedly re-opening cursors, the proper solution in the database would be to close them in your code but set the [session_cached_cursors](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/initparams186.htm) parameter so that the database maintained a [cache of the session's recently used cursors](http://dioncho.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-secret-of-session_cached_cursors/).  Having them not close their cursors is going to cause the `ORA-01000` error that you're seeing and will waste other server resources.